# What is the resolution order for items?

Tags: werewolv.es

There has been a lot of discussion in games about the correct order that events are resolved in regards to items.

Specifically, what is the precedence for Using an item, Having it stolen from you, Having it stolen by a killer, or Passing it to someone else?

Hopefully this should then allow answers to: "Can I use an item before it gets stolen from me?" and "If I try to pass an item and someone tries to steal it from me, who out of the pass-target or the thief gets the item?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was recently confirmed by Kirschstein (one of the moderators) on Discord:

1. Use
2. Steal
3. Kill
4. Pass

"Can I use an item before it gets stolen from me?" -> Yes
"If I try to pass an item and someone tries to steal it from me, who out of the pass-target or the thief gets the item?" -> The thief will get the item.

Further clarification was also added: If two thieves (or thief + potion) are used on the same target that is also the target of a kill, the thefts will bounce and the killer would get the item.